# Php Domain Filter Validates Invalid Domains And Invalidates Valid Domains

Tags: php, dns

I trying to validate domains with php domain filter.
But it's not working. Why ?

```
<?php

$url = 'http://stackoverflow';
$domain = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
        
if(!filter_var($domain,FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN))
{
    echo "Invalid Domain: $domain"; echo '<br>';
    echo 'LINE: ' . __LINE__;
}
else
{
    echo 'Valid Domain: ' .$domain;
    echo 'LINE: ' . __LINE__;
}

?>
```

I get echoed:
**Valid Domain: stackoverflowLINE: 15**

It seems aslong as the url contains "http://" regardless if the url contains a tld or not, the php filter accepts it as a valid domain.
Here's the proof ....

```
<?php

$url = 'stackoverflow.com';
$domain = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
        
if(!filter_var($domain,FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN))
{
    echo "Invalid Domain: $domain"; echo '<br>';
    echo 'LINE: ' . __LINE__;
}
else
{
    echo 'Valid Domain: ' .$domain;
    echo 'LINE: ' . __LINE__;
}

?>
```

This time, I get echoed:
**Invalid Domain:
LINE: 10**

Note the invalid domain is not getting echoed. Why ?

How to fix this ? How would you code it ?

In short, this FILTER is not working ....

```
filter_var($domain,FILTER_VALIDATE_DOMAIN
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The output is as expected. When you try to parse an URL-like string `stackoverflow.com` (which isn't an URL really, because the scheme is missing), then `parse_url()` will treat this string as `path` not as `host`.

Therefore, the variable `$domain` is `null` and `filter_var()` fails as expected. You can modify your second example in a way that you add a dummy scheme if none is given:

```
$url = 'stackoverflow.com';
if (strpos($url, '://') === false) {
    $url = 'https://' . $url;
}
$domain = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
```